# You have no ..., do you? / don't you?

Tags: grammar

I would say do you in this situation because no makes it negative. However, when I say it out loud, do you sound weird and don't you fits better. Which one is correct?

Ex: 1- You have no interest in me, do you?
    2- You have no interest in me, don't you?

Comment: It doesn't sound weird, at all (mostly because when I say this sentence out loud I emphasize the _no_).